# QField Sensors don't work via QField Cloud

Tags: qfield, qgis-cloud, qfield-cloud

I love the ability to interface with external sensors in QField; it's proven to be a great help.
I have noticed however, that it only works when I copy the package to my tablet manually ie via "cable transfer".
When syncing a project via QField Cloud the sensors don't appear at all in QField.

I wonder whether anyone else is experiencing this issue and has found a workaround (or perhaps I've missed something).
The sensors are the most important factor for me, so if needs must then I'll be cable syncing; but I'm greatly missing the convenience of syncing via Cloud in my application.